# elFinder (2.1.11) contextmenu is disabled in bootstrip model

Tags: elfinder

When an elFinder (2.1.11) html is loaded into bootstrap modal (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). The context menu is disabled. What is the problem with the model. or there is some best way to load the elfinder in bootstrap modal.
If we initialize elfinder not in modal it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of elFider <= 2.1.11. It was fixed on develop branch. Please wait release 2.1.12 or You can try [nightly build](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/archive/2.1.zip).